# How I will delete one of my project from JIRA?

Tags: jira

I have created 5 project in JIRA. I now want to *delete* one of these projects. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are an admin of Jira, you can delete the project through the "Jira Administration -> Project" page.

- click "Action" which is the last column
- Click "Delete" for deleting your project